# My script to compare two excel files is not working

Tags: vba

So I am writing a script to compare two excel files.

I'm using a For loop in the first workbook to get the references I want to find in the second workbook (6450 rows long so that no For loop, way to slow)

I have been looking for some way to use the VLOOKUP thing but i could not make it work Here is the code :

```
For i = 7  to numLines ''numLines is the number of used lines of the first workbook

    If '''test to get out of the LOOP
objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("D"&i)="" AND objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("H"&i)="" AND objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("L"&i)="" Then

        i = numLines

    Else '' here i get the reference (the 6 first digits of the first workbook and I try to find it in the second)

        If objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("D"&i)<>"" Then

            Reference = Mid(objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("D"&i),1,6)

            Set table_lookup = objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range( "C1:C" & numLines2 )
            cell = objExcel.Workbooks(Str2).WorksheetFunction.vlookup(Reference, table_lookup, 0, False)
            MsgBox cell.row
            MsgBox cell.column

        End If

    End If

Next
```

Comment: Please add a description of the error you are getting or the expected behavior in order to provide a proper guidance for solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to switch to the "find" method instead of the vlookup that does not seem to work on vba

```
For i = 7  to numLines
    If objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("D"&i)="" AND objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("H"&i)="" AND objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("L"&i)="" Then
        i = numLines
    Else
        If objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("D"&i)<>"" Then
            Reference = Mid(objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("D"&i),1,6)
                Set r = objExcel.Workbooks(Str2).Sheets(1).Range( "C1:C" & numLines2 )
            Set matched = r.Find(Reference)
            If Not r.Find(Reference) Is Nothing Then
                objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("R"&i).Value = matched.Offset(0,0).Value
                objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("S"&i).Value = matched.Offset(0,1).Value
                objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("T"&i).Value = matched.Offset(0,2).Value
                objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("U"&i).Value = matched.Offset(0,3).Value
                objExcel.Workbooks(Str1).Sheets(1).Range("V"&i).Value = matched.Offset(0,6).Value
            End If            
        End If
    End If
Next
```